# If Wolverine regenerated a limb, would it be covered in adamantium?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men, wolverine, adamantium

We've discussed Wolverine regenerating his body after nuclear explosions, but his adamantium-laced skeleton was left in tact afterwards.

After Magneto ripped the adamantium from his body, Wolverine has had his bone claws broken and they grew back due to his healing factor.

In [The Age of Apocalypse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adamantium#Adamantium_in_the_Ultimate_Marvel_Universe), Cyclops was able to break adamantium with his optic blasts.

Assuming his adamantium covered skeleton was broken by something other than [the Muramasa Blade](http://marvel.wikia.com/Muramasa_Blade) (which inflicts wounds which do not heal), would his body regenerate the adamantium covering as well?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Apparently, the adamantium-laced bones *heal*:

> **Adamantium Beta**: The only known occurrence of Adamantium Beta was
>   during the Weapon X Project. By the second part of the procedure when
>   they laced his bones with Adamantium there was a reaction with his
>   healing factor that bonded metal and bone. **As a result the Adamantium
>   "heals" just as his bones do**.

From: http://marvel.wikia.com/James_Howlett_%28Earth-616%29#Equipment

**Edit**: Couldn't find references to this outside the above article. Can regular comic readers corroborate?

Comment: Marvel's [own wiki](http://marvel.com/universe/Adamantium) refers to the adamantium beta and the fact that it is a new, separate material which does not inhibit normal bone functions, but does not specifically mention the adamantium healing itself. [comicvine's](http://www.comicvine.com/adamantium/18-40759/) page on adamantium, however, does. I'd like to find some more direct confirmation from Marvel somewhere.

Comment: So could he farm adamantium by chopping off his arms?

Answer (score 7):

No, because adamantium [was not originally part of is body](http://marvel.wikia.com/Wolverine_%28James_%22Logan%22_Howlett%29#The_Weapon_X_Program), so his body cannot regenerate with it. Add to this the dificulty to [synthesize true adamantium](http://marvel.wikia.com/Adamantium#True_Adamantium). Also note than :

> It also turned out that the presence of the adamantium slowed his mutation process down, his healing factor treated it like a foreign substance in the body and tried constantly to expel it.
>   -- [marvel.wikia Wolverine article, Magneto's Revenge section](http://marvel.wikia.com/Wolverine_%28James_%22Logan%22_Howlett%29#Magneto.27s_Revenge)

So his body wouldn't regenerate including a *foreign substance*.

Comment: That's true for the movies, but appereantly in the comics, they can heal.

Answer (score -2):

His Body Can heal Adamantium because his body bonded with the Metal basically treating it as one, his "armour" is considered Adamantium Beta. It is the same Strength as Primary Adamantium but it is a biological substance which is Affected by his healing Factor, Every time Wolverine gets limbs or parts of him Cut off by either the Samurai Blade or anything that can in fact Cut Adamantium. He will regrow it back as bone. But given sustained time to recover the adamantium will Regrow with it. It just takes substantially longer to heal due to its "indestructible" properties. Based on the MCU they havent Informed the Fan base that it is Possible. But he also has had help from Magneto to help speed up the healing due to his Mutation of being able to control and alter any Metal substance

Answer (score -2):

When the adamantium was ripped out it did not grow back. It was stolen by apocalypse from Cyber and reimplanted. It doesn't regenerate nor did weapon x make his DNA somehow produce inorganic material that is also toxic to his system. Dumb.

Comment: The question wasn't about the adamantium regenerating after it's been ripped out. The scenario in question specifies the skeleton still being covered in adamantium.