# Did Wolverine's bones regenerate before being enhanced with Adamantium?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine

Wolverine had healing powers from the very start. Before Wolverine had his skeleton enhanced with Adamantium, his bones were breakable as shown in *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*.

Did his healing power apply to his bones? If his natural bones were broken, would they have regenerated?

Comment: You should just formally ask in the question title: **Before Wolverine had Adamantium, did his bones regenerate?** or even **Does Wolverine's bones regenerate?** It's straightforward question for a title. The body should then go into more elaborate detail. This is a good way to organize and convey your question on this site. If you could edit it to something like this, it would be great and I'm sure others will find the question more readable and attractive to click on. Welcome to the SF&F SE site.

Comment: `his bones were breakable as shown in X-Men Origins: Wolverine` - So did they or did they not regenerate at that point in the movie?  Your answer should be right there...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.

Even humans bones regenerate at a slow rate. So Wolverine, as a mutant with healing factor-- his bones would regenerate, but at a considerably fast rate. As mentioned in a comment, without adamantium, his healing factor is even greater, as when it was in him, his body was constantly healing.

In the [X-Men Origins: Wolverine](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0458525/) movie, which you mentioned, he had his bone claws broken by Sabertooth before he had adamantium placed on his skeleton. It obviously grew back.

As mentioned in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/14366/1042), the [The Muramasa Blade](http://marvel.wikia.com/Muramasa_Blade) (the second one) is able to reduce Wolverine's healing efficiency.

Also see the question: [How much of Wolverine has to be left to heal?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12486/1042)

Comment: Worth adding: in the comics, without adamantium, his healing factor is even more extreme.

Comment: What if his bones were slied in half?

Comment: @ShwetabhShekhar I have added more information into my answer. Commenting is fine, but try to be thorough in including all your concerns and question aspects into the original question body. This site is for asking questions and getting them answered, not for extended discussions and infinite *what if* scenarios.

Comment: @shweta if you *do* want a discussion, come to [chat].

Comment: Also in latest movie "Wolverine" (2013) his adamantium claws are broken. But the bone inside regenerates pretty quickly.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Wolverine's claws can grow back almost immediately, but they would grow back as bone claws and they don't grow back the same way. They would still be 9-10 inches long and the same width and length as before, but the bone structure or the pattern of the bone claws would be different. If you were to remove an adamantium bone then it would likely just regrow as normal bone, not adamantium, but there have been a lot of rumours that the adamantium does grow back, [that it is beta-adamantium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/14512/23243).

Comment: Honestly, I don't know that you added anything to spong's answer...

Answer (score -2):

When his healing ability is not affected, he can regenerate his bones about 6 times slower than his muscles. Skin and muscles take 5-10 seconds, bones 30 sec-1 minute.

You need to chop off his whole head to kill him, like Spawn.

In *X-Men Origins*, everybody was asking the same question. *The Wolverine (2013)* showed the correct speed of his 100% healing factor.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  You'll find that answers stand a better chance of upvoting if you can provide backing references for statements you make.  Anything that you can reference from the canon to support the statements in the first paragraph ?

Comment: The "correct" speed of his 100% healing factor has changed from writer-to-writer.