# How could this Adamantium piece be destroyed in The Wolverine?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, marvel, adamantium, the-wolverine

In [The Wolverine](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1430132/?ref_=sr_1) there is a scene in which

> Wolverine's Adamantium claws get sliced off by the Silver Samurai.

I know about the Silver Samurai's ability of generating a *tachyon* field surrounding (usually) his sword, but I thought this couldn't cut through Adamantium.

So, **how could this happen?**

Comment: I haven't seen the movie, nor followed the comics for a long time.. But I seem to remember the Silver Samurai wielding one of the two [Muramasa Blades](http://marvel.wikia.com/Muramasa_Blade); at least one was made with a portion of Logan's soul, and inhibited healing of wounds it produced.  Logan himself identified stated "This is the only thing in the world that can put me down for good."  That being said, I'm guessing the movie one is the first blade, not Logan's but they may have combined/crossed them and given it the ability to sever adamantium as necessary to kill Logan as he said.

Comment: Whats really interesting is that if that part regenerates, then Wolverine would be a never ending source for adamantium beta...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### This is a failure of canon and writing regarding the issue of indestructible metals. Marvel has made little effort to describe Adamantium in any given detail and it defies the rules that most metals use regarding taking damage or being destroyed.

[image]

### TLDR

Given the premise that the [Silver Samurai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Samurai) was supposedly capable of [generating a tachyon field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyons_in_fiction) (read that as a rare high-energy field) surrounding an already super-sharp blade forged of True Adamantium and wielded with superhuman strength and precision, this might be capable of being part of the TVtrope "[Crowning Moment of Awesome](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/SugarWiki/MomentOfAwesome?from=Main.CrowningMomentOfAwesome)" allowing the claw to be broken.

- I also note that the Marvel characters when they come to the big screen are also not quite as powerful, irresistible or capable as they are seen in the comics. Is this an attempt at realism or simply a production consideration when the character is converted is a matter of debate.

### Building the Case

[**Adamantium**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adamantium) comes in a variety of flavors and capacities for absorbing or resisting damage. The original premise of Adamantium was that once it was set, it could not be broken by anything less than a force of cosmic origin (beings such as [Galactus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactus), [the Silver Surfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Surfer), [Odin](http://marvel.com/universe/Odin), [Zeus](http://marvel.com/universe/Zeus) or other such senior deities) or that of an Omega level mutant (including [Franklin Richards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franklin_Richards), [Jean Grey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Grey#Phoenix_Force) as the Phoenix or [Magneto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magneto_%28comics%29)).

- **Primary Adamantium**: Made only once mixing Adamantium and Vibranium together. Never duplicated, and considered one of the most indestructible materials in the Marvel Universe. Only found in [Captain America's (Earth-616) shield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America%27s_shield).
- **True Adamantium:** When Primary Adamantium couldn't be made, they created the next best thing, called True Adamantium. Nearly indestructible only beings of incredible capacity, capable of manipulating cosmic forces, altering reality, or using the very rare molecular re-arranger technology. Found in places like [Ultron's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultron) nigh-indestructible body.
- **Adamantium Beta:** After Wolverine was exposed to Adamantium during the bonding process, his regenerative powers altered the nature of the Adamantium allowing it to be regenerated like his normal skeleton. (**Don't ask because this makes no sense to me either**.) This Beta Adamantium is supposedly as strong as True Adamantium but that is unlikely since his bone structure would be as porous as his bones were originally.

**This would make his bones almost completely unbreakable except by forces capable of doing incredible damage dealing or by being able to bring an incredible amount of force on a tiny segment of his bone structure.**

- Wolverine's Adamantium-laced bones and claws (which were also bones) are made of "Adamantium Beta" which is supposedly as indestructible as True Adamantium but can be affected by incredibly powerful force weapons (like Cyclops' optic blast), Vibranium ([the anti-metal variety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibranium)) weaponry and other Adamantium weapons.
- The limitation of Adamantium Beta is that it is still more vulnerable to destruction than the hardest versions of Adamantium and therefore it is theoretically possible for it to be damaged or broken.

### Apocrypha

Marvel has never truly explained how the bonding process allows Wolverine to repair his broken bones that are laced with Adamantium. The wiki at Comicvine also lists this information without a reference.

> Adamantium Beta: The only known occurrence of Adamantium Beta was during the Weapon X Project. By the second part of the procedure when they laced his bones with Adamantium there was a reaction with his healing factor that bonded metal and bone. As a result the Adamantium "heals" just as his bones do.

Comment: If Movie-Wolverine's skeleton was laced with Adamantium-Beta as you mention (and discussed [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14476/5184), his claws should not have grown back as uncovered bone, as they did.

Comment: at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyons_in_fiction under comics, it says the tachyon field generate can cut through anything but adamantium lol I thought it was originally heated blade that cut through wolverine's claws which made less sense since heated metal is softer

Comment: I'm a couple years late here, but I always thought that  Adamantium Beta was an organic alloy of the metal. Beta is also found on Cyber, since the process of bonding it to his skin alters the chemical properties of the metal.

Answer (score 15):

The Silver Samurai's sword was made of adamantium. It had a heating mechanism built in. Super-heated adamantium can cut through adamantium. This was established as canon on the previous Wolverine movie where Deadpool uses heat vision on Wolverine's claws and then Wolverine decapitates Deadpool, whose body was laced with adamantium. This was confirmed by Gavin Hood on the DVD commentary.

Comment: Heat should have no affect on adamantium as written in the Marvel Universe canon. Decapitating Deadpool was simply cutting between his adamantium-laced vertebra at exactly the right spot. This same technique could be used against Logan/Wolverine if one is skilled enough.

Comment: Not according to the director in the DVD commentary.  I don't have the direct quote, but it is specifically addressed.

Comment: Then they have deviated from the original writings of the Marvel Universe. Adamantium once forged cannot be affect by anything less than cosmic-level forces. As I said, bad adaptation of the canon.

Comment: @Thaddeus That may well be, but the original question was looking for a movie universe explanation. The contradiction is easily explained: the properties of Adamantium are different in Earth-199999 as compared to Earth-616. ;)

Comment: Yes, I thought I mentioned that. Not a contradiction, a "bad adaptation of canon". Heat has nothing to do with it. If it does, then nothing established in the Marvel Universe means anything at all. These are just people who LOOK like heroes from the Marvel Universe...

Comment: @Thaddeus I'm just curious, what do you mean "Decapitating  Deadpool was simply cutting between his adamantium-laced vertebra at exactly the right spot"?

Comment: This is a spine. The [bone](http://www.cedars-sinai.edu/Patients/Programs-and-Services/Spine-Center/Anatomy-of-the-Spine/Images/Spinous_pr-10864.jpg) is covered in adamantium but the cartilage isn't...

Answer (score 10):

This is basically a "It looks cool in the move so lets do it." thing.  Based on everything in the comics, Adamantium once hardened is pretty much indestructible, even by something made of adamantium or similarly invincible metal (Uru (Thor's Hammer), Adamantite (Hercule's Mace))  They did a test in the Avengers where Thor, one of the physically strongest beings in the Marvel Universe, hurled his hammer at a tube made of adamantium with everything he had.  It put a small, almost unperceived dent in the tube, that was it.  So, by comics standards, the Samuri's sword and Wolverines claws shouldn't have been able to cut through each other, even when super-heated.  But as its been noted, the films often don't follow cannon.

But I wouldn't worry too much, I doubt He'll be without his adamantium claws for long, especially with Magneto back in the picture and Brian Singer at the helm.

As a side note, there is a metal called Antarctic Vibranium, also know as anti-metal, that can pierce adamantium.  if they had made the Samuri's sword out of that, there wouldn't have been any argument at all....just another indication that most filmmakers just don't care enough to do a little research.  But, that's just how it is I guess.

Answer (score 4):

Adamantium was said that once it was set it could not be re melted so if the sword is red hot then it will not be softened resulting in heated adamantium striking cool adamantium, if this is true then the heated adamantium would crack the cooled adamantium much like a glass cup warm from the dishwasher and pouring cold water in, it would shatter, only in this case it is backwards

Answer (score 3):

I read somewhere that the Silver Samurai could not cut through Wolverine's claws...

His(Silver Samurai) mutant ability allows him to generate a field of tachyonic energy around his katana that allows it to cut through almost any material on earth except for adamantium.

http://www.comicvine.com/silver-samurai/4005-3174/
(Powers and Abilities section

Comment: Interesting tie-in to the comics, but the Silver Samurai you linked to (Kenuichio Harada) is technically the grandson of the Silver Samurai in the movie (Ichirō Yashida). And I don't believe it was ever mentioned in the comics or the movie that Ichirō Yashida has any mutant powers.

Answer (score 1):

It's Cannon in the comics wolverine fully regenerates from 1 drop of blood! that includes the adamantium.

The silver samurai never could break or cut through adamantium.... I couldn't believe it when the silver samurai in the movie cuts through wolverines claws and they regrow as bone. No one out side of cosmic level powers and the hulk can break them, even then the hulk is usually only able to bend them.

And the hulks just a few steps below cosmic level powers when hes at his strongest. magneto (one of the strongest mutants) cant even break adamantium and he can literally control magnetic fields, although again often bends the claws and such..

Comment: Magneto literally ripped the adamantium out of Wolverine's body in the comics. If he can do that, he can "break" it as well.

Comment: FYI, a "[cannon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannon)" is a form of artillery. The word you're looking for is "canon".

Comment: The whole "one drop of blood" thing was a one-off deal. It wasn't Logan's healing factor that did it, but rather the mystical properties of the M'Krann Crystal that the blood landed on. And yet people keep bringing it up. Sheesh.

Answer (score 1):

the actual silver samurai doesn't have adamantium anything... he has the power to encase his weapons and self in a kind of telekinetic energy field.

This is the cannon set in place in the comics universe.

"The first Silver Samurai is a mutant with the ability to generate a tachyon field, with which he can surround anything[citation needed]. He commonly uses his power on his sword, enabling it to cut through nearly anything, except substances as hard as adamantium."

"The second Silver Samurai possesses a technologically-advanced suit of armor, which grants him the ability of flight and protection from many conventional attacks. In addition to carrying two katana blades, Shingen possesses a number of armaments and gadgets, such as an energy cannon built into the right wrist of the suit"

Source :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Samurai

Comment: There is no reason for you to have posted two answers. they can easily be combined.

Answer (score 1):

If I put it this way, I take two knives of the same material, heat one up really hot, and then slice together I'm sure the warm one will have a bigger dent than the cold one. It's not like metal vs butter, both metals can withstand the same temperature meaning if the heat doesn't melt one why would it melt the other enough to cut through.

Comment: Difficult to see how this addresses the question.  You express an opinion but don't support it with any references to cannon material.

Answer (score 1):

There's a scene in X-Men Origins: Wolverine where Stryker is talking to Agent Zero about Logan's indestructibility.  I don't remember the exact words, but they go along the lines of "The only think that can pierce his adamantium skeleton as an adamantium bullet."  Based on the logic set by this in universe canon movie, the only thing that can damage Logan's adamantium skeleton is something else made of adamantium.  Silver Samurai's swords are, not only energized, but also made of adamantium.