# Wolverine's claws

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine, adamantium

At the end of "*The Wolverine*" Wolverine got his claws cut off, but the bone claws still remained along with his adamantium skeleton. Will his bone claws therefore get coated with adamantium as time passes?

Comment: More related discussion in [How could this Adamantium piece be destroyed in The Wolverine?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/38655/5184)

Comment: While the comics can be used as a reference for movie questions, I don't think questions that are explicitly only about the comics are proper duplicates of this question.  The movies are a separate universe from the comics with different canon and rules.

Comment: My question was about the comics, but the second one was about the same movie and even the same scene.

Comment: @Cody For future questions, please consider marking major plot points as spoilers...

Answer (score 3):

If this is solely for movie cannon, the only way to know is to wait till the next movie and see what script writers have wolvie snikt-ing.

If comic cannon, there are conflicting opinions "officially" it would heal back just as his bones as it is Adamantium Beta (though I would have thought at a slower rate as it is known to retard his healing factor a bit), yet when Magneto removed the Adamantium from wolvie it did not heal back. Whether there has been an explanation for this confliction or not I dont know

Comment: When Magneto removed the adamantium from Wolverine's body, he removed *all* of it. The adamantium beta heals with his body, but it can't if there is none there to begin with.