# What are the essential films one needs to watch before "Logan"?

Tags: suggested-order, x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, marvel, logan

My best friend and I are planning to go see *Logan* soon, but she doesn't have the time to watch eight X-Men movies beforehand.

What are the most important movies to have seen before *Logan*?

Comment: Related: [In which order should I watch the X-Men movies to know Wolverine's full sequential story?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/69106/)

Comment: “she doesn't have the time to watch eight X-Men movies beforehand” — she is what we gently and fondly yet very firmly refer to around here as a *lightweight*. We all had to sit through *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*, I don’t see why she gets away with skipping it. (Plus I think you’re not including Deadpool in your count of X-Men movies. It’s the best one!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Realistically, you don't need to see any of them, as long as you are aware of who Logan and Charles Xavier are and what their basic personalities are like. This movie was filmed in such a way that it's stand-alone.

There are a few casual references to *X-Men 1* and the story *sort-of* picks up where *X-Men: Age of Apocalypse* leaves off (as far as Logan is concerned, anyway). But you don't really need to know those stories, only that the X-Men did exist and the world did know about mutants.

If you did want to catch up on Logan's personal backstory, since *Logan* takes place in the rebooted timeline, you really only need *Days of Future Past* and *Age of Apocalypse*. Those two movies will explain the key piece of history you might need -- how the bad guys ended up knowing so much about mutants. The the other movies (*X-Men 2, X-Men 3, X-Men Origins: Wolverine*) have all be mostly erased from the timeline, so other than giving you a general sense of Logan and Xavier as characters, you won't get anything meaningful out of them.

Comment: You didn't mention *The Wolverine*. While *Logan* is still a largely standalone movie, it does continue the character arc from that movie of Logan wanting to die. I would recommend it for anyone who likes the character and wants to get a deeper understanding of his personal motivations.

Comment: I find the objection to not watch the other movies because they are erased from the timeline to be odd, since Logan's memories were the one thing that didn't get erased in the timeline reset from *Days of Future Past*. Also, I thought *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* and *X-Men 2* were still in continuity since Logan said that Dr. Rice's father gave him the adamantium (*Origins*) and that Logan killed him (*X-Men 2*). *X-Men 3* is definitely out though given deaths being undone.

Comment: I think you are reading a lot into this answer that's not there. I never said you _shouldn't_ watch those movies. I said you didn't _need_ to, because the plot of those movies was nullified. (Everything that happened after ~1975 was undone by _Days of Future Past_, and in particular, Fox was _trying_ to erase _Origins_ because of how screwed up it was. Wolverine got his adamantium in the facility seen in _Age of Apocalypse_, where the young mutants released him, and he murdered pretty much everyone in the facility at that time.)

Comment: While it's true that the older films were erased from the timeline, the first two still offer useful context for someone who had never been exposed to X-Men. If you already know the characters from comics or the animated series they can be skipped, but if you didn't know anything about the X-Men, you can still follow the plot of _Logan_, but it will lose a lot of its significance.

Answer (score 4):

*Logan* is fairly self-contained, so you don't need a ton of backstory, but a good understanding of Logan's character does help. The ones I found most important were:

- *X-Men*
- *X-2: X-Men United*
- *X-3: The Last Stand*
- *The Wolverine*
- *X-Men: Days of Future Past*

Following this list will give you a thorough understanding of the X-Men universe and Wolverine's background.

*X-Men* and *X-2* are the most important, especially if you're not already familiar with the X-Men universe from other media such as comics or animated shows. These two films will get you oriented in the universe and introduce Wolverine and his backstory. *X-2* is especially important for Wolverine.

*X-3* is only necessary if you want to watch *The Wolverine*. I haven't seen *The Wolverine*, so it's not essential, but it sounds like it clarifies some of the plot threads a little, especially as regards *Days of Future Past*.

You could skip *Days of Future Past* at your discretion, but I like the extra perspective it gives to *Logan*. It sheds light on the relationship between Logan and Professor X, and its ending adds an extra note of tragedy to *Logan* when you think about what's happened in between the two movies.

So, really, at an absolute minimum, you could get away with just *X-Men* and *X-2*, but watching *The Wolverine* and *Days of Future Past* will provide useful context for Logan's character and relationships, and *X-3* is necessary to follow the plot of *The Wolverine*.

As for the other movies:

*X-Men Origins: Wolverine* can be skipped. It has some nice contextualizing information about Wolverine's past, though it's a pretty terrible film overall. (Watch it if you want to understand some of the Easter eggs in *Deadpool*, though.)

*First Class* can be skipped. It has the least Wolverine content of any X-Men movie. It's a good movie, one of my favorites of the series, but not vital to seeing *Logan*.

I haven't seen *X-Men: Apocalypse*, but per Kutulu Mike's comment, the post credit scene is a direct lead-in to *Logan*. You can skip or watch at your discretion.

Comment: the only reason to see _Apocalypse_ is because, as far as Logan himself is concerned, _Logan_ is a direct continuation. Mostly, you just need the post-credit scene.

Comment: The big advantage with watching *The Wolverine* is that it begins Logan's character arc of wanting to die, which is a major theme for *Logan*.