# Are the joints of Wolverine his weakness?

Tags: marvel, wolverine

If adamantium is not covering Logan's joints,  can I cut his arms or legs there?
Or even the neck?

Comment: Yes, but it would only grow back anyway, wouldn't it?

Comment: For sure... but with adamantium?

Comment: Related: [How much of Wolverine has to be left to heal?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12486/1359).

Comment: I meant.. the new part will come back with no adamantium, since its not part of his DNA.

Comment: And a shoot between the ribs will reach his heart... the ribs must be keep separated to allow breath.

Comment: Re: regrown parts having adamantium or not, refer to [If Wolverine regenerated a limb, would it be covered in adamantium?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14476/5184)

Comment: Given the nature of knee caps and other joint-protecting bone parts, I'm curious how you intend to cut so precisely as to cut through the ligiments and not in any way encounter his bone, while also cutting fast enough to not affect his rapid-healing factor.  Even then, I can at the very least imagine that his cartilidge has some adamantine in it as well.

Comment: @Zibbobz if so, I'll not see Marvel's movies or comics anymore. 1) Cut through the ligaments like my mother do with a chicken. 2) How fast is rapid-healing factor to avoid cut centimeters of cartilage. 3) Is adamantium flexible or have Logan robot-like joints?

Comment: @MagnoC Having cut through the ligiments of a chicken before, I can tell you that to do so properly without hitting bone at least a little bit, you have to be really, really precise or persistent.  While you could do that with Wolverine, you'd have to knock him out and tie him up to avoid any resistance at all first.  And I don't know how fast Wolverine's healing is, but I believe it is very fast.  Adamantium is not flexible at all, but wolverine manages to move somehow with it infused in his bones, so it's as possible as any other part of Wolverine's body.

Comment: I knock him out with gas. He have not super human force, so tie his hands in proper way will hold him. I'll have all time I need. What about bones of the cervical spine?

Comment: His spine can be severed; http://smg.photobucket.com/user/sinister_samurai/media/Wolverine/Wolverine_050_032_033.jpg.html

Comment: @Richard Can't look at such an image at the moment, but it's not after he was cut by the Muramasa, is it?

Comment: @Zibbobz - Torn in half by the hulk

Comment: The speed of Wolverine's healing factor is 100% dependent on the exact frame of the exact issue/show/movie it's in. There have been times where he heals as fast as he's damaged, and there have been times where it's taken months for wounds to heal.

Comment: Technically, Wolverine has a ["virtual immunity to poisons and most drugs"](http://marvel.com/universe/Wolverine_%28James_Howlett%29). Depending on the writer/story, trying to knock him out with gas may be impossible.

Comment: The Wolverine powers depends on the convenience. I think he can kill the Superman now. Someone please close this post. I'm the O.P.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/17619/20533), his ligaments are in fact a weak point.  And while it doesn't show him getting cut apart...

[image]

...Tearing him apart is entirely possible.

Note that this image is of Ultimate Wolverine, and not the main (Earth 616) Wolverine, who may or may not have sturdier ligaments.

Comment: You should probably note that the image is of Ultimate Wolverine,and not the main (616) Wolverine, just for posterity sake.

Comment: @Monty129 Added.

Comment: What part will regenerate and becomes the real Wolverine?

Answer (score -1):

ALL of Logan's bones were covered. Joints as well. The tendons and ligaments can be cut, and severed bu they grow back. He's been blasted, burnt, and melted with only the skeleton parts remaining ( i.e. left arm blasted away to nothing but skeletal remains) somehow he can still use that hand.

Comment: Do you have any references for these points?

Comment: Recognizing that, as a one-rep user you cannot share links with us, naming your references would work just as well.

Answer (score -1):

in Age of Apocolypse Wolverine has his hand blown off at the wrist.  Age of Apocolypse Wolverine is the same physically as 616 Wolverine as the divergence happened in the 616 universe as opposed to a what if story.